# Is there a way to restore odoo installation with out uninstall?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I don't want to have to reinstall everything. I have an error on the server where odoo does not run. It is a database (xml) which gives me the error. So I want to restart everything. Is it possible to do it without entering web / database / manager?

I would like to have a clean installation without having to purge everything and install again.

## Edit

I have a community odoo installation on a local development server with debian installed.

I have no problem deleting everything and starting over, but I don't want to do the whole installation process all over again.

This is the error I am getting with his command:

```
odoo -p 8070 -dev=reload,xml -i base
```

2022-01-06 13:23:42,561 13626 ERROR xml odoo.modules.loading: Database xml not initialized, you can force it with `-i base`

```
2022-01-06 13:23:42,575 13626 ERROR ev=reload odoo.modules.loading: Database xml not initialized, you can force it with `-i base`
2022-01-06 13:23:42,582 13626 INFO xml werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Jan/2022 13:23:42] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 - 6 0.006 3.747

2022-01-06 13:23:42,588 13626 ERROR xml werkzeug: Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 306, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 294, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/server.py", line 441, in app
    return self.app(e, s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 113, in application
    return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 88, in application_unproxied
    result = odoo.http.root(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1306, in __call__
    return self.dispatch(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1272, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_wrapped)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/werkzeug/middleware/shared_data.py", line 220, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/http.py", line 1463, in dispatch
    ir_http = request.registry['ir.http']
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/odoo/modules/registry.py", line 176, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: 'ir.http' - - -
2022-01-06 13:24:42,606 13626 ERROR xml odoo.sql_db: bad query: SELECT latest_version FROM ir_module_module WHERE name='base'
ERROR: relation "ir_module_module" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT latest_version FROM ir_module_module WHERE name='base...
                                   ^

2022-01-06 13:24:42,607 13626 WARNING ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_cron: Tried to poll an undefined table on database xml.
2022-01-06 13:24:43,639 13626 ERROR xml odoo.sql_db: bad query: SELECT latest_version FROM ir_module_module WHERE name='base'
ERROR: relation "ir_module_module" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT latest_version FROM ir_module_module WHERE name='base...
```

Comment: This is very vague! Please add actionable items.

Comment: Yes please add more information. If an XML is wrong there should be some ways to fix that without removing the whole database. But you also have to tell us what access possibilities you have (only web interface? or even database access?).

Comment: @CZoellner web interface is not working. Is showing me `Internal Server Error` I edited my question